# 'dispatch' is not a function when argument to mapToDispatchToProps() in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building an small application with redux, react-redux, & react. For some reason when using mapDispatchToProps function in tandem with connect (react-redux binding) I receive a TypeError indicating that dispatch is not a function when I try to execute the resulting prop. When I call dispatch as a prop however (see the setAddr function in the provided code) it works.

I'm curious as to why this is, in the example TODO app in the redux docs the mapDispatchToProps method is setup the same way. When I console.log(dispatch) inside the function it says dispatch is type object. I could continue to use dispatch this way but I would feel better knowing why this is happening before I continue any further with redux. I am using webpack with babel-loaders to compile.

My Code:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setAddresses } from '../actions.js';
import GeoCode from './geoCode.js';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/lib/flat-button';

const Start = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    },

    setAddr: function(){
        this.props.dispatch(
            setAddresses({
                pickup: this.refs.pickup.state.address,
                dropoff: this.refs.dropoff.state.address
            })
        )   

    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-6">
                        <GeoCode ref='pickup' />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-6">
                        <GeoCode ref='dropoff' />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-6">
                        <FlatButton 
                            label='Does Not Work'
                            onClick={this.props.onSubmit({
                                pickup: this.refs.pickup.state.address,
                                dropoff: this.refs.dropoff.state.address
                            })} 
                            />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-6">
                        <FlatButton 
                            label='Works'
                            onClick={this.setAddr} 
                            />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onSubmit: (data) => {
            dispatch(setAddresses(data))
        }
    }
}

const StartContainer = connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Start)

export default StartContainer
```

Comment: I was having this issue and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47565406/1399491) helped me solve it

Answer (score 350, accepted):

If you want to use `mapDispatchToProps` without a `mapStateToProps` just use `null` for the first argument.

`export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Start)`

Comment: This is what I have been looking for. Now I know if I just want to dispatch some actions.

Comment: This is exactly something I was looking for. Thanks for the perfect solution. What if we don't have to use mapDispatchToProps in any of our component ? Is it the same way we have to handle that scenario ?

Comment: If you don't need `mapDispatchToProps`, just don't add that argument to `connect`: `connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)`

Answer (score 116):

You are just missing the first argument to `connect`, which is the `mapStateToProps` method.  Excerpt from the Redux todo app:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)
```

Comment: is it mandatory to use this method? This method just catches state what if we dont need this method?

Comment: @MuneemHabib see inostia's answer for how to not supply this method if you don't need it

Answer (score 24):

Use

```
const StartContainer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Start)
```

instead of

```
const StartContainer = connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Start)
```

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by interchanging the arguments, I was using

```
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps, mapStateToProps)(Checkbox)
```

which is wrong. The `mapStateToProps` has to be the first argument:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Checkbox)
```

It sounds obvious now, but might help someone.

Answer (score 4):

I needed an example using `React.Component` so I am posting it:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Redux from 'react-redux';

class NavigationHeader extends React.Component {

}

const mapStateToProps = function (store) {
    console.log(`mapStateToProps ${store}`);
    return {
        navigation: store.navigation
    };
};

export default Redux.connect(mapStateToProps)(NavigationHeader);
```

Answer (score 4):

### Issue

Here are a couple of things to notice in order to understand the connected component's behavior in your code:

**The Arity of `connect` Matters: `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)`**

React-Redux calls `connect` with the first argument `mapStateToProps`, and second argument `mapDispatchToProps`.

Therefore, although you've passed in your `mapDispatchToProps`, React-Redux in fact treats that as `mapState` because it is the first argument. You still get the injected `onSubmit` function in your component because the return of `mapState` is merged into your component's props. But that is not how `mapDispatch` is supposed to be injected.

You may use `mapDispatch` without defining `mapState`. Pass in `null` in place of `mapState` and your component will not subject to store changes.

**Connected Component Receives `dispatch` by Default, When No `mapDispatch` Is Provided**

Also, your component receives `dispatch` because it received `null` for its second position for `mapDispatch`. If you properly pass in `mapDispatch`, your component will not receive `dispatch`.

### Common Practice

The above answers why the component behaved that way. Although, it is common practice that you simply pass in your action creator using `mapStateToProps`'s object shorthand. And call that within your component's `onSubmit` That is:

```
import { setAddresses } from '../actions.js'

const Start = (props) => {
  // ... omitted
  return <div>
    {/** omitted */}
    <FlatButton 
       label='Does Not Work'
       onClick={this.props.setAddresses({
         pickup: this.refs.pickup.state.address,
         dropoff: this.refs.dropoff.state.address
       })} 
    />
  </div>
};

const mapStateToProps = { setAddresses };
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Start)
```

Answer (score 2):

A pitfall some might step into that is covered by this question but isn't addressed in the answers as it is slightly different in the code structure but returns the exact same error.

This error occurs when using `bindActionCreators` and not passing the `dispatch` function

**Error Code**

```
import someComponent from './someComponent'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { someAction } from '../../../actions/someAction'

const mapStatToProps = (state) => {
    const { someState } = state.someState

    return {
        someState
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        someAction
    });
};

export default connect(mapStatToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(someComponent)
```

**Fixed Code**

```
import someComponent from './someComponent'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { someAction } from '../../../actions/someAction'

const mapStatToProps = (state) => {
    const { someState } = state.someState

    return {
        someState
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        someAction
    }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStatToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(someComponent)
```

The function `dispatch` was missing in the Error code

Answer (score 2):

React-redux 'connect' function accepts two arguments first is mapStateToProps and second is mapDispatchToProps check below ex.

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Index);`
`

If we don't want retrieve state from redux then we set null instead of mapStateToProps.

`export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Index);`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing in the last statement. As we don't have mapStateToProps, so the statement will be like below

```
const StartContainer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Start)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do not provide `mapDispatchToProps` as a second argument, like this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Checkbox)
```

then you are automatically getting the dispatch to component's props, so you can just:

```
class SomeComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(ACTION GOES HERE);
  }
....
```

without any mapDispatchToProps

Answer (score 0):

i am using like this.. its easy to understand first argument is mapStateToProps and second argument is mapDispatchToProps in the end connect with function/class.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

Comment: if you dont have first argument then just pass null / undefined and then second argument..

Answer (score 0):

Sometime this error also occur when you change the order of Component Function while passing to connect.

**Incorrect Order:**

```
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps, mapStateToProps)(TodoList);
```

**Correct Order:**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when i wrote :
export default connect **(mapDispatchToProps,mapStateToProps)(SearchInsectsComponent);**
instead of
export default connect **(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(SearchInsectsComponent);**